# How can I set up an external HDD that functions just like a shareable flash drive?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, external-hdd

I have partitioned an external HDD on linux (gpt, ext4) and mounted it under `/mnt` and would like to use it as a storage device for the whole team, meaning everyone would have all permissions to all files even on other Linux machine (unless one changes the ownership and mode *manually*). If someone creates a new file on their PC, someone else on another PC would also be able to read and write those files. Running `sudo chmod -R 774 /mnt/NewDrive/` does the job but not for new files created after running the command. Am I jeopardizing the security of the machine this external HDD is connected to? What is the safest practice?

Finally, how can I set up such an external HDD that functions **just like a shareable flash drive**?

Answer (score 0):

When creating new files, the permissions are calculated from inverse `umask`, so you need to set `umask` which is inverted value. So for `774` permission it should be `003` I think

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I just need to figure out what are all the dmask, umask, etc.